# Generating sub tables in R

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I need to translate some Python code to R. What I need to do is sample random rows from a larger table multiple times so I can use it for later. Here is an illustration:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

test_table <- data.table(replicate(10, sample(0:1, 10, rep=TRUE)))
test_table
```

Gives a 10 x 10 table populated with (on some particular run):

[image: Full table]

So for instance one can get a sample:

```
sample <- sample_n(test_table, 2)
sample
```

Which might look like:

[image: A particular sample]

However, I don't understand the result when taking multiple samples:

```
kSampleSize <- 2
kNumSamples <- 3

samples <- replicate(kNumSamples, sample_n(test_table, kSampleSize))
samples
```

may give:

[image: Samples]

But it doesn't really look like a "list of `sample`". I expected `samples[1]` to give a result similar to `sample` but instead I get a weird result (varies per run):

```
1. 1 0
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I misinterpreting the output? Is expecting a "list of `sample`" something to expect in Python but not in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Random Sampling in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676348/multiple-random-sampling-in-r)

Comment: See the answer in the possible duplicate, but you just need to add `simplify = FALSE` to `replicate`

Comment: The default value of `simplify` is `TRUE` which coerces to type `list` in this case, which is why you got the data structure you did.

Comment: @Mako212 Ah ok! Thank you! I think it may be a duplicate as well, but it seems like there is a lot more going on in that question to the point that my question still may be useful for others.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll move my comment to an actual answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `simplify` argument within `replicate` that determines whether R attempts to simplify the returned object to a less complicated data structure.

`simplify` defaults to `TRUE`, and in this case it collapses the returned list of data frames down into a single object of type `list`. Specifying `simplify = FALSE` turns off this behavior.

```
kSampleSize <- 2
kNumSamples <- 3

replicate(kNumSamples, sample_n(test_table, kSampleSize), simplify = FALSE)
```

Returns a list of three data frames, preserving the original data structure:

```
[[1]]
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1:  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   1
2:  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1   1

[[2]]
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1:  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   0
2:  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   1

[[3]]
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1   1
2:  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   0
```